# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (python)

Tags: python

**have this code:**

```
import os

def get_video_duration(video_path: str) -> float:
    duration_command_stream = os.popen(
        'ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1' + video_path
    )
    duration_command_output = duration_command_stream.read()

    return float(duration_command_output)
```

**error:**

```
[default @ 000001d1cf80b400] Unable to parse option value "1videosaHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yYWdlLm1pbmlnZ2lvZGV2LmZyL3Rlc3Qvc3RvcnkubXA0.mp4" as boolean[default @ 000001d1cf80b400] Failed to set option 'nokey' with value '1videosaHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yYWdlLm1pbmlnZ2lvZGV2LmZyL3Rlc3Qvc3RvcnkubXA0.mp4' provided to writer context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    videos_to_upload = build_videos_to_upload(video_url, video_path)
  File "C:\Users\shrim\Downloads\instagram-story-poster-main\instagram-story-poster-main\build_videos_to_upload.py", line 10, in build_videos_to_upload
    duration = get_video_duration(video_path)
  File "C:\Users\shrim\Downloads\instagram-story-poster-main\instagram-story-poster-main\get_video_duration.py", line 9, in get_video_duration
    return float(duration_command_output)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: There should be the problematic value at th end of the exception, could you verify your error and give the value ?

Comment: add a space `nokey=1'` -> `nokey=1 '` ?

Comment: do `print(">" + str(duration_command_output) + "<")` and you'll understand why the value can't be a float

Comment: ALWAYS ! when there is an error regarding variable(s) : print them all and verify that they are what you think